# How can I catch CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED in my code?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have created a custom class for an NLP project.
This class tries to fit a Keras model, but I often have CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED during training (it seems to be caused by memory issues). These errors can occur after hours of training.

As I can't find a fix for the CUDA error, I tried to implement a workaround :

- I added a ModelCheckpoint to save the "best" model at each epoch
- If an error occurs during training, I reload the best model & clear the GPU memory.
- I resume the training with the reloaded model

I tried this by simulating errors (KeyboardInterrupt), and it works.

However, I can't find a way to catch the CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED error. It seems it just stops the python process (low-level error ?).

[image: CUDA ERROR]

Does anyone know how to catch these CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED ?

Code snippet :

```py
def custom_fit(self, some_arguments):
    ...
    try:
        fit_history = self.model.fit(
            x_train,
            y_train_dummies,
            batch_size=self.batch_size,
            epochs=self.epochs,
            validation_split=None,
            validation_data=validation_data,
            callbacks=callbacks, # Includes ModelCheckpoint 
            verbose=1,
        )
    except: # CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED not catched
        ...
        # Reload model
        # Clear GPU memory
        # Resume training (recursive call to this function)
```

Comment: You are assuming tensorflow will raise a Python exception when a CUDA runtime error occurs in its internals. Are you sure that really happens?

Comment: No, I'm not sure at all. I was expecting a way to catch any kind of error in the training. I'm far from being an expert, but I assumed there would be a way to catch any exit signal directly in my python script.

Comment: Can you try setting a hard limit on the total GPU memory as shown in the [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#limiting_gpu_memory_growth) and check if it works. Thanks!